# Sherlock S04E03: how does the prison glass disappear?

Tags: sherlock

In the Final Problem, how does the glass of the prison Eurus was held in really disappear? If it didn't exist at all, then how come the writings on the glass wall exist?

edit:
I am actually looking for the 'how'. Yes, Sherlock explains that they were suspended, but is it possible? Or did the show runners knowingly didn't show us how because we would have noticed the 'how'?

Comment: The writings are basically SUSPENDED SIGNS(without any glass behind them). There is no glass wall; just signs that look like they have been etched on a glass. 

Moreover, Eurus explains that she uses a throat mike that directly connects her to the speakers. When she turns it off, we can hear her talk normally(without the speakers) to Sherlock.

Comment: @Rippy yeah.. so it seems.. just that it doesn't look from where it's suspended. how it is suspended. no wires visible that could be helping it stay suspended

Comment: And even if the signs are suspended through some means, where do they go and why don't they hinder Eurus's way when she hits sherlock with her arms and jumps on him..?

Comment: Suspended doesn't actually mean hanging from strings. It could also mean bolted at one or 2 ends. If you observe, then the elephant glass sign is mounted to the door pane from the right side.

Comment: @Rippy yes. the matter of concern is the "maintain distance" sign..

Comment: There only 2 possible explanations here, either the height of the glass wall  is just upto the  "maintain distance" sign or the glass is only in that specific area i.e. behind the sign only rest of the space below and above the sign is empty.

Comment: Invisible threads are a classic tool for magicians. With adequate light, they are very difficult to notice. Especially if you are not looking for them and your focus is diverted by the magician.

Comment: The glass also reflects the people in the room

Comment: Exactly. Reflections are visible on several occasions, *including* in the centre pane where the glass "disappears". We know the signs are fake etching, but how is that centre pane withdrawn without Sherlock noticing, and how could Eurus be so certain he'd be sufficiently distracted?

Comment: the elephant glass sign in attached to a pole but I don't know about the other one.

Comment: The reflections are in earlier scenes, there are NOT any reflections in the glassless scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a picture (on Pinterest), of the rehearsal of the scene where Sherlock meets Eurus.

[image]

You can clearly see the sign is (actually) held in place via vertical rods running through both ends.

Comment: so you mean the show runners knowingly 'erased' those rods just like they do when showing stunts and 'erase' the wires from which actors are carried.
that's what i wanted to know. I guess the logic the writers portray here is moot now.

Answer (score 14):

This is made clear in the dialogue by Sherlock and a quick angled shot.

> "The signs..you suspended the signs"

The text wasn't etched on the glass...they were (replacement?) signs suspended in place...although we do not see *how* they are suspended.

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's what couldn't be followed. suspended signs? and not visible?

Comment: We don't see how the big sign was suspended...but it's clear that the text wasn't **on** the glass as you asked.